# How can I use YouTube's old notifications pane?

Tags: youtube

This is YouTube's new notifications pane:

[image]

It just clumps everything together in a difficult-to-read manner, and when I click on a notification to try and see the whole text it takes me away from the video I am currently watching, rather than opening in-the-frame like it used to.

Here's what it used to look like, and what it currently looks like everywhere else on google:

[image]

How do I get the older notifications pane on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is unintegrating Google+, which is why the Google+ notifications had to go. You can still access them on Google+ (or any other gcon site, really), but that will probably stop working without warning when they cut the cord for good.

You cannot switch back to Google+ notifications on YouTube itself, but what you can do is:

1. send feedback at the bottom of any YouTube page to let them know you want in-line replies and grouping and such back
2. use addons/extensions like Tubebuddy, which emulate certain features more or less well.

Comment: I don't understand why YT can't keep the nice notifications pane

Comment: Imagine YouTube as a house which is getting the entire first floor entirely remade. You can live nicely on the ground floor of that house without noticing anything and you can even still use parts of the first floor, and until now: including the notifications room. But now it was that rooms turn to get remade, and if you look at it now it is just a concrete box with not much in it. There will go nice paintings and furniture in it again, but probably after all of the other work has been done on the first floor.